# Python: uniqueness in list of lists

Tags: python, list

given à list of lists:

```
L = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [1,2,3]]
```

how to get a list where each list is unique:

```
L = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5]]
```

thanks

Comment: What have you tried already? How do you define uniqueness? Is `[1,2,3]` the same as `[3,2,1]`?

Comment: Most solutions for making lists contain only unique elements should work equally well for lists of lists.

Comment: @thegrinner yes i've tried already, and search google and so for an answer which i couldn't find anything

Comment: @drewmm the usual `list(set(L))` doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of sub-lists:

```
In [11]: list(map(list, set(map(tuple, L))))
Out[11]: [[3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Better yet, you should probably just move to using sets of tuples as your data structure.

Comment: Adapting that to retain order: `sorted(map(list, set(map(tuple, L))), key=L.index)`

Comment: Not the most efficient method, but it is concise.

Comment: More efficient (in theory; for small lists, could easily be much slower) order-preserving approach: `OrderedDict((tuple(x), x) for x in L).values()`.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of jinking around but how about this?

```
[list(el) for el in set(tuple(el) for el in L)]
```

It works because lists can't be compared to one another but tuples can. The error message gives it away if you try to directly make a set from a list of lists:

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Careful, `list` can be compared to each other `[1] == [1]` works just fine.  `list` aren't hashable though since they are mutable objects.

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. Fortunately you can depend more on the Python error message

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [1,2,3]]
newlist = []
for item in L:
    if item not in newlist:
        newlist.append(item)
```

Comment: This'll work but can be a little inefficient when `L` is large, because each time it has to scan through all of `newlist` for each `item` in `L`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a set of tuples and then back to a list.

```
L = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [1,2,3]]
setL = set(tuple(i) for i in L) 
newL = list(list(i) for i in setL)
print newL
```

[[3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]